# É possível fazer upload de imagem e renomeá-la apenas com Java Script?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, diretório, request

Tem alguma forma de pegar o arquivo de imagem da requisição, salvar ela em algum diretório e alterar o nome dela do servidor utilizando `JavaScript`?

**Obs:** Pode ser de qualquer maneira, ou usar qualquer *framework* *(`AngularJS`, `jQuery`)*

Comment: Javascript é utilizada no cliente, ou seja, no seu navegador apenas, você precisa de um código server para fazer isso. Você pode até usar Javascript se escrever um código server usando NodeJS.

Comment: @RicardoPontual não tem problema, pode ser salvo no lado do cliente mesmo

Comment: Por razões de segurança `Javascript` não tem comandos com permissão pra acessar o disco no navegador do cliente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andei pesquisando, e realmente utilizando-se apenas de `JavaScript` é impossível fazer upload de arquivos, por motivos de segurança só é possível carregar arquivos no lado do cliente, ou seja, não podemos renomear, mover ou algo do tipo *(Manipular)*.

A menos que utilizemos [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/) para criarmos uma `API` com `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 0):

Não, por questões de segurança você não tem controle para manipular arquivos do lado do cliente, você pode renomear depois que recebe no lado do servidor.